# On input click, keep input field visible when virtual keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

I got a challange here and would like to get some help from your experience.

This app has floating (sticky) header (where you see store details and the tabs with Details and Contacts) and also a floating (sticky) bottom bar and the content scrolls behind them.

When a user clicks on an input field the virtual keyboard shows up.

The problem is, when the virtual keyboard shows up, if the input field is in a place where the bottom bar will stay, the input stays covered by the bottom bar.

For example the city field was near the center and the user clicked it, the virtual keyboard is shown and the input field for city is covered by the floating bottom bar.

The expected result was that the city field should be placed right above the BottomBar.

[image: Mobile App Issue with virtual keyboard]

I am using window resize event to detect when the keyboard shows up. I am also using a document.querySelector(":focus") to detect the item "clicked" and checking if it's an input or textarea using the nodeName.

I have tried to apply element.scrollIntoView({block: "center"}); but if the element is initially at the center of the screen it will not scroll and will be covered by the bottom bar when the virtual keyboard shows up.

This is the javascript I am applying currently:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input, textarea");
var container = document.querySelector(".screen > .content");

window.addEventListener("resize", function(e) {

var targetEl = document.querySelector(":focus");
var bottomBar = document.querySelector(".bottom-bar-wrapper");

if(targetEl.nodeName.toLowerCase() === "input" || targetEl.nodeName.toLowerCase() === "textarea") {
    var scrollY = Math.floor(targetEl.getBoundingClientRect().top + targetEl.getBoundingClientRect().height + bottomBar.getBoundingClientRect().height);
        
    container.scrollTo(0, scrollY);
}

});
```

It's the solution that has worked best so far but not sure if it's the more eloquent one.

The challenge part is that when a user is already typing on an input and click on another input the scroll calculations return wrong values and it scrolls to a very strange position where the clicked input is not even close.

What can be happening for the position of the elements to return wrong values?

How would you approach this?

I've created a mockup on JSFiddle that kind of replicates the issue, html and css wise.

https://jsfiddle.net/marioandrade/L5f2n3vm/14/

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Hey Mario, thank you for your detailed question! Your request is crystal clear.
Can you please share with us the HTML and CSS code so that we can assist you?

Comment: Hey @perplexyves unfortunantely I can't due to legal terms with client confidentiality. Here's a fiddle I think kind of replicates the issue, at least layout wise. https://jsfiddle.net/marioandrade/L5f2n3vm/14/